# AngularFire - Wait for query before subscribing

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a service that performs a query. This query is triggered from any component that needs the query to run. However, I would like to populate an array within the component with the results of the query. (I'm fully aware that you can use `| async` with angularfire, but certain specifications require me to have an array)

In the example below, the component checks to make sure the user is signed in to obtain the user id and then calls the service to perform the query.

After that, I subscribe to the albums observable so that my array will be updated effectively.

Even though the below works, it doesn't feel right to call `this.subscribeToList();` with no certainty that the query has run.

What's the best way to update the `queryAlbums` function to ensure that `this.subscribeToList();` is only called AFTER the `this.albumsService.queryAlbumsList(user.uid);` has effectively been executed?

**Component.ts**

```
async queryAlbums() {
  const user = await this.authService.isLoggedIn()
  if (user) {
    this.albumsService.queryAlbumsList(user.uid);
    this.subscribeToList();
  }
}

subscribeToList(){
  this._subscription = this.albumsService.albums.subscribe(v => {
    this.myArray = v;
    console.log(v);
  });
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
queryAlbumsList(user_id: string) {
    this.albumsCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`albums`, ref => ref.where("users", "array-contains", user_id))
    this.albums = this.albumsCollection.valueChanges({ idField: 'id'}).pipe(shareReplay())
}
```